# How to stop the boxeeservice process on OSX?

Tags: macos, boxee

I have boxee installed on my osx box and can't figure out a way to stop the boxeeservice process - I just want it turned off for the time being. I tried to kill -9 the process and it just returns. Seems like it's in one of the launchctl processes but nothing in the /Library/LaunchAgents folder indicates that there's a boxee plist item.

Where is the boxeeservice process being launched from? And how can I stop/start the process when I want?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - it's in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ folder as tv.boxeee.helper.plist. So

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/tv.boxee.helper.plist
```

stops the process quite nicely.